# jScrollpane is working but not creating the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I have jScrollpane working on my mac at home, however I have just uploaded it to my CentOS web server and I am having issues. The scroll bar appears as it should, however I have set "showArrows: true" but I am not getting any arrows. Also, when I inspect the element in either firefox or chrome, both on windows and mac the class="jspContainer" and all of the other elements, jspPane, jspVerticalBar etc do not appear in the html. Giving this is the case it would make more sense if there were no scrollbar at all.

I am using this in drupal, so I am not sure if this is because there are other javascripts running. The major issue is, that without the containers etc being created by the javascript, I can't theme the scroll bar as the divs aren't created for the css to act upon.

I had the same issue initially on my mac, I commented out some other js I had running in jQuery(document).ready then it started to work. I put back all of the other stuff I have running in jQuery(document).ready after starting jScrollpane and it kept on working. I have restarted apache, cleared caches etc on the mac to make sure it isn't just working from cache and I've done the same on the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed the jScrollPane module from drupal instead of adding the scripts manually, solved the problem. I should remember to look for a module first before trying to do it my self, it is a lot quicker.